# Laravel Nova - Save multiple rows to database on create

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I'm converting a Laravel app that was using Backpack across to Laravel Nova.

One of my models `Images` allows the user to add multiple images with a base set of information from the initial form. The form in this instance asks how many images are in the series via a dropdown and then has a number of relevant fields that will be used for all of the new images being added. When saving, in the controller, I'm using the following eloquent feature to run a number of tasks and insert the required number of rows:

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request){
  //Get some info
  //Make some tweaks
  //Use for loop to save multiple records
  for ($k = 0; $k < $addim; $k++){
    //Do some stuff      
    parent::storeCrud(${"request"});
  }
}
```

This works perfectly and inserts however many records are required.

In Laravel Nova, I can't see a way to use this same approach. Using an event listener in the model doesn't seem like the right way to save multiple records and I can't find any reference to a controller function I can use to achieve this.

I would really appreciate some thoughts and guidance on the best way to complete this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has stumbled upon this type of problem.

You can use [Laravel Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers).

In order to restrict the event to be fired only when resource is created and only using nova you can declare Observer in `NovaServiceProvider.php` as follows

```php
/**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        Nova::serving(function () {
            Image::observe(ImageObserver::class);
        });
    }
```

Above code will only be triggered when your image object is modified using nova system only.

For ref Observer code will look like following

```php
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Document;

class ImageObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Image "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Image  $image
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Image $image)
    {
        //logic to create multiple records
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the saving event in an observable

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events

Comment: But how can you restrict this to only happening when the resource is created in nova?